# Return Values from Ansible Role Tasks in a loop are only registered for the last item

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a role `ovirt_vm_add_disk_role` that creates a new disk for a VM with `ovirt_disk` module.

In that role I register the variable `disk_info` which contains the results of the `ovirt_disk` module:

```yaml
- name: "Update disk information"
  ovirt_disk:
    auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
    activate: true
    name: "{{ disk_name }}"
    poll_interval: 10
    vm_name: "{{ HOSTNAME }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: disk_info
```

The contents of `disk_info` looks like:

```json
"msg": [
    {
        "active": true,
        "bootable": false,
        "disk": {
            "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/6814659f-f89c-4b6e-b067-f09272b1095b",
            "id": "6814659f-f89c-4b6e-b067-f09272b1095b"
        },
        "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/vms/3d76975e-b3e2-4fa5-8c27-5b3eca1825eb/diskattachments/6814659f-f89c-4b6e-b067-f09272b1095b",
        "id": "6814659f-f89c-4b6e-b067-f09272b1095b",
        "interface": "virtio_scsi",
        "logical_name": "/dev/sde",
        "pass_discard": false,
        "read_only": false,
        "uses_scsi_reservation": false,
        "vm": {
            "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/vms/3d76975e-b3e2-4fa5-8c27-5b3eca1825eb",
            "id": "3d76975e-b3e2-4fa5-8c27-5b3eca1825eb"
        }
    }
]
```

When I call that role for a single disk everything is fine and I can use `disk_info` in the playbook that called the role.

However when I need to loop over the role to add more than one disk I can only see `disk_info` for the last iteration.

Loop:

```yaml
  - name: Add DATA Disks loop
      vars:
        disk_name: "{{ HOSTNAME }}_{{ item }}"
        disk_size: "{{ disk_size }}"
        disk_storage: "{{ invstorage_domain }}"
      include_role:
        name: ovirt_vm_add_disk_role
      with_items: "{{ disks }}"
      register: asm_data_devices
```

When adding to Disks with variable `disks: ['DATA01','DATA02']` then `disk_info` does only contain information about `DATA02`.

Tried to register the outcome of the loop in variable `asm_data_devices` but it does not contain return values of `ovirt_disk` module at all:

```json
"msg": [
    {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "include_args": {
                    "name": "ovirt_vm_add_disk_role",
                    "public": true
                },
                "item": "DATA01"
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "include_args": {
                    "name": "ovirt_vm_add_disk_role",
                    "public": true
                },
                "item": "DATA02"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So how can I get the return values from `ovirt_disk` module in outer playbook calling the role for all items of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Registering the result of an include returns the result of the include, not of the included tasks.

The easiest solution in your case is to move the loop from the include to the relevant task:

```yaml
- name: "Update disks information"
  ovirt_disk:
    auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
    activate: true
    name: "{{ HOSTNAME }}_{{ item }}"
    poll_interval: 10
    vm_name: "{{ HOSTNAME }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
  with_items: "{{ disks }}"
  register: asm_data_devices
```

Since you now [register with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop), `asm_data_devises.results` will be a list where each item is the result from a single iteration.